# How to determine which PHP file spawned/created php5.cgi process in Apache?

Tags: php, apache

After a few hours, an Apache server slows to a crawl, and upon investigating, I can narrow it down to one website (each website has a separate user).

This website has multiple php5.cgi processes running, while a normal site has 1 or 2, and is killing the server.

My guess is that a script or plugin is causing these problems, is it possible to determine which script spawned/created a process?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is really running as a CGI, you can read the request variables for a php5.cgi process by looking at the process's environment variables in `/proc/<pid>/environ`.

There is no equivalent way to do this for FastCGI processes, though.